# ng-repeat on array of objects not working..?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of objects like this:

```
var data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "age": 20,
    "name": "Janell Mcintosh",
    "gender": "female",
    "email": "janellmcintosh@zilphur.com",
    "phone": "+1 (906) 555-2575"
  },etc..
];
var keys = Object.keys(data[0]);
```

I am trying to display this data in a table. The keys are columns, and all of the object's values are supposed to go in the relevant column. Here is what I am trying:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="key in keys">
            {{key}}
        </th>
    </tr>

    <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
        <td ng-repeat="key in keys">
            {{row['"'+key+'"']}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This doesn't work. I am trying to put quotes around the key because the JSON I receive has the keys *and* values in quotes. The data/variables are stored properly, I just don't know how to access them.

Am I doing something incorrectly here?

```
{{row['"'+key+'"']}}
```

I'm just trying to add quotes to the key.

[View sample plunker here:](http://plnkr.co/edit/3nlpCdZPotzoeGCnYlQE?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the double-quotes around the key values.  (Javascript parses keys the same whether or not the quotes are present, so `var data = { "id": 1 }` is completely equivalent to `var data = { id: 1 }`.

So all you need is:

```
<td ng-repeat="key in keys">
    {{row[key]}}
</td>
```

See [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XWgM0qAJhApjyARX9ANb?p=preview).

Comment: Shoot. Can't believe I didn't try this first. I will accept when the timer is up. Follow up: Why can't I do `{{row.key}}`?

Comment: @JosueEspinosa `row.key` looks for a property named "key".  `row[key]` looks for a property name of the value stored in the `key` variable.